# How to open alexa skill on browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

i have created a recipe recommendation alexa skill, and when i say "Alexa, send me the recipe", then it should open a browser amd show mw the result in phone. Is this possible??

I have created a skill. It is working fine in alexa developoer console. but want this on smartphone browser.

Comment: Think about the execution context... The Alexa skill is running on a server somewhere in Amazon. It is not able to make something open in a browser because browsers _request_ information from a site, they do not randomly _receive_ information from somewhere. You could ask the user to go to a particular URL on a server that you control, and then that web server could retrieve information that is displayed. Or, if you know the user's phone number, you could send an SMS to them with a link. The hard part is getting the user's information to know how to contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- [Alexa for apps](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-for-apps/about-alexa-for-apps.html) (recommended) :

You will be able to send push notification on the Alexa App of the user that will redirect them to either a web link or within a mobile app.

> Note: Alexa for Apps is a developer preview and might change as Amazon receives feedback and iterates on the feature. To use this feature, you must [register for the preview](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/response-api/alexa-for-apps).

- [Alexa Web API For Games](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/web-api-for-games/alexa-games-about.html):
  It will open the browser on the device. Only compatible with device that have a screen. (will not send you a notification on the phone)